# Unable to get double click event in OpenCV for python

Tags: opencv, python-3.x

## OpenCV with python(MAC OS X EL Capitan)

I'm creating a demo project to track mouse events in openCV. using standard mouseCallback from openCV.

following is my code for the same.

**drawWithMouse.py**

```
#!/usr/local/bin/local/python3
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

#Mouse callback function
def draw_shape(event,x,y,flags,param):
    print("event : ",event)
    if event == cv.EVENT_LBUTTONDBLCLK:
        cv.circle(img,(x,y),100,(255,0,0),-1)

#Create a black image, a window and bind the function to the window
img = np.zeros((780,780,3),np.uint8)
cv.namedWindow('DrawWithMouse')
cv.setMouseCallback('DrawWithMouse',draw_shape)

while(1):
    cv.imshow('DrawWithMouse',img)
    if cv.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == 27: #ANDing with 0xFF as my machine is 64 bit
        break

cv.destroyWindow('DrawWithMouse')
```

with this implementation i'm always getting mouse down and mouseup event and only single click event. i'm unable to get double click event(EVENT_LBUTTONDBLCLK). value for this constant is 7.

i'm getting following output [image: event : 1 is mouse down and event: 4 is mouse up]

Answer (score 0):

I just tried running your code, to me everything seems fine. I click down and hold a 1 comes up, I release and there is a 4. When I double click there is a 7. This however doesn't work if the mouse is moving. Try keeping your mouse still while you double click or try another mouse[image: Terminal is in the bottom right]

Comment: I'd tried this on two different computers. Both are MAC machines.

Comment: And I'm unable to get double click on any of them with two different mouse.

Comment: @RajendrasinhParmar the same occurs to me on macos

Comment: @Fred did you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to workaround problem with time measurement, for example time.clock() (not precise butthe simplest) and calculation of time difference between click and previous one. If time is less than threshold perform double click action.

```
time =0
thresh = 1
#Mouse callback function
def draw_shape(event,x,y,flags,param):
  print("event : ",event)
  if event == cv.EVENT_LBUTTONDBLCLK:
    if time.clock - time < thresh:
       //double click
    time = time.clock()
    cv.circle(img,(x,y),100,(255,0,0),-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I freshly downloaded opencv-python in El Capitan for Python 3 since I didn't have it:

Downloading opencv_python-3.3.0.10-cp36-cp36m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl (43.8MB)

Ran the example code and left button double click worked fine, creating lots of blue circles.  I then tried to make it fail.  The only thing I found that came close was setting double click speed to the highest mark in Systems Preferences / Mouse:

[image]

I found a significant difference between the highest setting and the second highest.  Searching the web, using either the Fast or Slow extreme can be troublesome with double clicking.

Have you verified that your double clicking works in general?  Although I can't find it currently, I believe there were once settings that converted double clicks into two individual clicks and other potential Macintosh quirks.  Is X-Windows in any way involved with your setup?

Good luck.

Comment: i tried that. it's long time now. i should try it again. as everything is updated now in my system.

Answer (score 0):

For people like me who want to `copy-paste`:

```
import time

last_time = None

def double_click(self, event, x, y, flags, params)
    """handle double click"""
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:

        if last_time is not None and time.time() - last_time < 1:
            cv2.circle(img, (x, y), 20, (255, 0, 0), 2)
           last_time = None
        else:
           last_time = time.time()
```

You can use the last parameter `params` to pass your frame when setting the callback:

```
cv2.setMouseCallback("image", double_click, img)
```

Answer (score 0):

Temporary simple hack (until someone comes up with a real answer):

Change event from 'EVENT_LBUTTONDBLCLK' to any non double click events (e.g. 'EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN')

Answer (score 0):

ENV: macOS High Sierra, OpenCV 3.4, Python 3.7.0

Encountered the same problem. 
Tried Apple magic pad / Logitech wireless mouse, the same result.

NO HELP with adjusting the preference on mouse click speed in macOS.

Just change the desired event from (EVENT_LBUTTONDBLCLK) to (EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN) will do.

Comment: I think this might be related to some other problem related to MAC pointing device driver and OpenCV interaction. However, your solution for EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN seems to do the trick.